# Unable to execute "Facebook Like" from within Android application

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, facebook-android-sdk

From within my Android application, i am trying to implement a simple "Like Button" functionality.

We have already executed Facebook log in from the same app.
We have also created an Open Graph Like action & a Link object as well on our App's Dashboard.

This is the code that we are using to publish the like.

```
public static void likeFacebookPage(Context context,String pageUrl)
{
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("object",pageUrl);
    Request request = new Request(
        Session.getActiveSession(),
        "me/og.likes",
        params,
        HttpMethod.POST
    );
    Response response = request.executeAndWait();
    // handle the response

}
```

In the **pageUrl** parameter, we have:

```
http://www.facebook.com/<object_id>
```

"**object_id**" is the Id of the Link Object that we have created in Open Graph.

After executing the above method, the response object received as follows:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: -1, errorType: null, errorMessage: null}, isFromCache:false}
```

But the Like count is not getting updated, leading us to believe that this process is not working.

We have also included the permissions "**publish_actions**" & "**user_likes**" in our code as well as on the App Dashboard.

Kindly help us with configuring this functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i do have the same problem .. any solutions ?

Comment: same problem, any update??

Answer (score 0):

As described here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/ you publish a like to an object like so with the publish_actions and publish_stream permissions:

```
    Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
    Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(),
            FB_OBJECT_ID+"/likes", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, new Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                }
            });
    RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
    task.execute();
```

Where your FB_OBJECT_ID is simply the ID of the object. I.e if you want to like a photo, FB_OBJECT_ID would be the pid. For an album, FB_OBJECT_ID would be the aid.